# .htaccess 301 redirect remove the end of url

Tags: .htaccess, replace

I am not very knowledgeable with htaccess and I have searched for an answer and tried a few possible solutions from similar questions.  But no luck.
We have a wordpress site that we moved from `http://somesite.com/blog/` to just `http://somesite.com`  I have found the way to redirect it but here is the problem: the old url had the post number on the end so it looked like this:

`http://somesite.com/blog/blog-title-here/1234/`

the new link for that blog would be like this:

`http://somesite.com/blog-title-here/`

Can someone help me figure out a 301 htaccess redirect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/([^/]+) /$1/
```

or mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?blog/([^/]+) /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for your help! this works for this: http:--somesite.com/blog/blog-title-here/  but not this: http:--somesite.com/blog/blog-title-here/1234/  my main issue is how do I remove the last directory from the link "/1234"

Comment: So what is this doing wrong: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /blog2/([^/]+)/(.+) /$1/ [L,R=301]

Comment: that still didn't seem to work, this works fine http:--somesite.com/blog/blog-title-here/  but this still gives a 404 http:--somesite.com/blog/blog-title-here/1234/  so just to clarify I have this now: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?blog/([^/]+) /$1/ [L,R=301]  Thanks for your help

Comment: I understand somewhat what is going on with that it is basically saying that the rewriterule is to find blog directory and assigns $1 to anything after that except / does that actually mean that it will stop at / because I basically need to split everything after /blog/ and only keep the one right after it.

Comment: @topedge `blog/([^/]+)` matches everything after `blog/` and something after it. The grouping is only the "something after it, up to a slash". So for `/blog/blahblah/something`, **$1** is `blahblah`, and that's it. These rules work perfectly fine for me in a blank htaccess file , so you've either got something configured funny (like Multiviews) or you've got other rules that are conflicting.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I only have <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?blog/([^/]+) /$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule> in the htaccess file.  When I have /blog/blahblah/something it doesn't even try to redirect it it just gives a 404 but when I do this /blog/blahblah/ it works perfectly.

Comment: @topedge mod_rewrite isn't loaded then, try mod_alias